# What was the creature at the end of "What If...?" episode 1?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, marvel-what-if-2021

In the Marvel series *What If...?* what is the character at the end of episode 1? What is it known as? Does it have any comic book origin or it is created for the show specifically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe there is a canonical answer, but a strong possibility is [Shuma-Gorath](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Shuma-Gorath_(Multiverse)), a tentacled Elder God entity who frequently attempts to invade the world to consume it. As a frequent Dr. Strange villain, it would fit in that they might be teasing him prior to the second film, *Multiverse of Madness*

Not matching is that Shuma-Gorath is notorious for announcing himself upon arrival.

[image: Image of Shuma-Gorath appearing to consume New York]