# Is the dragon consumed by Doctor Strange in "What If...?" S01E04 the same as the one seen in "Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings"...?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dragons, marvel-what-if-2021, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In the fourth episode of Marvel's *What If...?* series, an alternate version of Doctor Steven Strange learns that he must consume mystic beings in order to reverse an absolute point in time in his universe. One of these beings is a dragon that looks very much like the dragon in *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*, that protects the village of Ta-Lo. Are they the same?

According to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253288/what-are-these-creatures-in-what-if-episode-4), the dragon "might" be Jormungand, but there are two of the dragons and both of them are red as is the dragon in Shang-Chi.

I would like to know if there is any evidence for or against the proposed theory.

[image: the dragon]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are these creatures in What If? Episode 4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253288/what-are-these-creatures-in-what-if-episode-4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's unlikely that they're the same creature.

The creature in *What If... Doctor Strange Lost His Heart Instead of His Hands?* is primarily reddish on the top half of its body, and primarily orange on the lower half, with no limbs that we can see. It also breathes fire, and has yet to be named in any official source as far as I'm aware.

We can't even say for sure that this thing is actually a dragon. It could be, but it could also be a giant serpent, like Jormungand, the Midgard Serpent (though I doubt it's him specifically).

[image]

[image]

The dragon in *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* is primarily white, with a red mane and underbelly, and clearly has two arms and two legs.

It's never shown to breathe fire, is first seen underwater, and the director, Destin Daniel Cretton, referred to it as a "water dragon", which suggests it's unlikely to be a fire breather.

> “The symbolism of the dragon in Chinese culture and mythology was too important, I think, to write off in that way,” he told Polygon. “So yes, there is a very significant water dragon in our movie. I would not name that dragon Fin Fang Foom.”
>
> <sub><sup>[No, the dragon in Shang-Chi is not Fin Fang Foom](https://www.polygon.com/22654505/shang-chi-fin-fang-foom-dragon-marvel)</sup></sub>

[It's also been released as a toy](https://marvel.hasbro.com/en-us/product/hasbro-marvel-shang-chi-and-the-legend-of-the-ten-rings-the-great-protector-dragon-figure-action-toy-for-kids-age-4-and-up:2A12793F-94A9-42CA-A46C-1468A65B8C24), the packaging of which names it as 'The Great Protector'.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks!