# Who are these characters in "What If...?" Season 2 Episode 9?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, marvel-what-if-2021

*What If...?* Season 2 Episode 9, titled "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?" shows several characters from the Marvel universe — some of whom I am not familiar with. Who are these characters?

Here are screenshots of the characters I am curious about:

###### Imprisoned "universe killers" 1

[image]

I believe Thanos is third from right, while Ultron might be the rightmost character. I'm not sure who the others are.

###### Imprisoned "universe killers" 2

[image] [image]
The second from the left looks like the child Peter Quill / Star-Lord. Also not sure who the others are.

###### Gnome character

[image]
Seems to be one of the imprisoned "universe killers" in a screenshot above

###### Huge, armored, winged, glowing monster with a powerful sword

[image][image]
This character gave (threw) a green sword in their possession to Captain Carter and Kahhori. This is along with Hela, Thor, and Xu Wenwu, who gave their crown, Mjolnir, and the Ten Rings, implying that this character's sword is also a powerful artifact.
[image][image]

###### Wild West gunslinger character

[image]
Looks like Loki, but I haven't noticed the character using Loki's powers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see a total of twelve so-called 'universe killers' (fully visible from head-to-toe) in the first three images in your question, each of whom I've attempted to identify below.

I believe the 'gnome character,' the 'huge, armored, winged, glowing monster with a powerful sword' and the 'Wild West gunslinger character' are all characters who were already shown in the first three images (specifically, the characters I've labelled as F, J and C, respectively).

> [image: Image of the "universe killers" from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of the "universe killers" from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "[What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/What_If..._Strange_Supreme_Intervened%3F)"</sub>

A. Hela
B. Xu Wenwu
C. Loki
D. The Collector
E. Thanos
F. Gnome
G. Ultron
H. Rocket Raccoon
I. Peter Quill
J. Hulk
K. Corvus Glaive
L. Thor

[Strange Supreme](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange/Corrupted_Doctor_Strange) helpfully identified three of the universe killers for us, about four minutes into the episode:

> STRANGE SUPREME: Let me see here; **Infinity Ultron**, I think you know... and **Thanos**... **Loki**... beings of untold power hell-bent on destroying their universes. You know, the usual.
>
> CAPTAIN CARTER: You're collecting universe killers.
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

He made this statement as the first of the two images above was shown on-screen. Based on the appearance of those characters, I believe he was referring to the ones I've labelled as G, E and C, respectively (naming them from right to left on that row, the same direction in which the 'camera' was panning in that shot).

Character G appears to be the version of [Ultron](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ultron) with the Infinity Stones depicted in *What If...?* S01E08 and S0109, and it makes sense for Strange to say that [Captain Carter](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Carter/Super_Soldier_Peggy_Carter) would know that version specifically, since they fought him alongside the other [Guardians of the Multiverse](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Multiverse) in the latter of those two episodes.

> [image: Image of Ultron from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>
>
> [image: Image of Ultron from "What If...?" S01E08.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S01E08 - "[What If... Ultron Won?](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/What_If..._Ultron_Won%3F)"</sub>

Character E looks like a version of Thanos as he was depicted in *Avengers: Infinity War* and *What If...?* S01E08. The Infinity Gauntlet is visible on his left hand. After Carter frees the universe killers, we see him more clearly later in the episode with the Infinity Gauntlet on the same hand.

> [image: Image of Thanos from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Thanos from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

Character C is harder to make out, but we get a closer look at him later in the episode and it's clearly the same gunslinging Loki-lookalike visible in the last image in your question.

> [image: Image of Loki from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Loki from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Loki from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

Aside from his uncharacteristic attire and weaponry, his appearance matches that of Loki as depicted in prior *What If...?* episodes such as S02E07, and since Strange stated that Loki was one of the universe killers whilst character C was on-screen, I believe it's reasonably safe to conclude that that's who he was referring to. Character C is the only character clearly shown on-screen in the episode who physically resembles the versions of Loki portrayed by Tom Hiddleston.

A version of [Hela](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Hela) is clearly shown to be one of the universe killers after they've been freed, and based on the distinctive headgear and body type of character A, I think we can safely conclude that they're one and the same.

> [image: Image of Hela from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Hela from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

A version of [Xu Wenwu](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Xu_Wenwu) is clearly shown to be one of the universe killers after they've been freed, and based on character B's long grey hair and topknot, I'd confidently conclude that they're one and the same.

> [image: Image of Xu Wenwu from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Xu Wenwu from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

Character D bears a strong resemblance to the [Collector](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Collector), a version of whom appears to be trading blows with a version of [Korg](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Korg) among the other universe killers (near the middle of the second image below) after they've been freed. It looks like the same version of the Collector depicted in *What If...?* S01E02.

> [image: Image of the Collector from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of the Collector from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>
>
> [image: Image of the Collector from "What If...?" S01E02.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S01E02 - "[What If... T'Challa Became a Star-Lord?](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/What_If..._T%27Challa_Became_a_Star-Lord%3F)"</sub>

Character F is clearly the same [gnome](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Gnomes) creature we see running around among the other freed universe killers later in the episode, and the same creature (or type of creature) that Strange Supreme absorbed power from in *What If...?* S01E04. Comments from [Ryan Meinerding](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ryan_Meinerding) quoted within [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260333/122024) indicate that that character was made up for the series.

> [image: Image of a gnome creature from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of a gnome creature from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>
>
> [image: Image of a gnome creature from "What If...?" S01E04.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S01E04 - "[What If... Doctor Strange Lost His Heart Instead of His Hands?](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/What_If..._Doctor_Strange_Lost_His_Heart_Instead_of_His_Hands%3F)"</sub>

Character H appears to be a version of [Rocket Raccoon](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Rocket_Raccoon), who's clearly shown among the other universe killers after they've been freed.

> [image: Image of Rocket Raccoon from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Rocket Raccoon from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

Character I is a dead ringer for the eight-year-old version of [Peter Quill](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Star-Lord) depicted in *What If...?* S02E02.

> [image]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E02 - "[What If... Peter Quill Attacked Earth's Mightiest Heroes?](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/What_If..._Peter_Quill_Attacked_Earth%27s_Mightiest_Heroes%3F)"</sub>

Character K appears to be a version of [Corvus Glaive](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Corvus_Glaive), who's clearly shown among the other universe killers (on the right of the second image below) after they've been freed. An identical-looking version of him was depicted in *What If...?* S01E02.

> [image: Image of Corvus Glaive from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Corvus Glaive from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

Character L is one of the harder ones to make out, but their outfit corresponds to that of the version of Thor who throws his hammer to Captain Carter and [Kahhori](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kahhori) later in the episode. I don't believe we've seen this specific version of Thor prior to this episode.

> [image: Image of Thor from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of Thor from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

I've saved character J till last, as it's the character whose identity I'm least confident of. That said, I'm pretty sure it's some type of Hulk. That face, the huge bare feet, the general body type, the brutish sounds he makes when he vocalises, the wholly green colour scheme... it all screams 'Hulk' to me. Admittedly, I've never seen a version of the Hulk that looks quite like this before, but since all the other universe killers depicted appear to be variants of pre-established MCU characters, I find it hard to see who else that could be other than a Hulk.

> [image: Image of a Hulk from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of a Hulk from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> [image: Image of a Hulk from "What If...?" S02E09.]
>
> <sub>*What If...?* - S02E09 - "What If... Strange Supreme Intervened?"</sub>

Comment: These are all spot on. I merely wish add a note on the last character, which looks like some sort of Hulk with wings. In the comics, the most famous hulk-like being with wings was Hulkling. In all fairness, this being looks more bestial than comic Hulkling and their wings are quite different but I still thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Ziggy - I doubt character J is meant to be a version of Hulking. This episode and the series as a whole doesn't seem interested in referencing characters who've only appeared in the comics. They seem to be mainly referencing characters (or variants of characters) who've already appeared in the MCU, especially prior episodes of _What If...?_.

Comment: They've also shown a tendency to make stuff up specifically for the series. The gnome character [was indicated](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260333/122024) to be made up for the series, and I believe Kahhori was made up for the series as well. With that in mind, I'm inclined to think this is a new variant of the Hulk, rather than a callback to an existing version with that design. Also, his outfit and weapons give me Asgardian vibes.

Answer (score 0):

The Hulk-Thor mashup is part of the 2022 run. That's the Odinsword with the ThorHulk merged. Hulk was a spaceship (of sorts) at the time; a body piloted by Bruce Banner.

[image: Hulk-Thor mashup]

More info at: https://screenrant.com/thor-hulk-strongest-avenger-combination-hero-powers-comics/

Comment: There is a resemblance to that hulkified version of Thor from _Thor Vol. 6_, but the character designs are somewhat different, and none of the other characters in the _What If...?_ episode seem to be taken directly from the comics, which leads me to believe that this one likely isn't either.

Comment: It's also worth noting that neither the Hulk nor Thor wielded a sword (or an axe) in the comicbook storyline you're referring to, and the Odinsword didn't appear in those issues at all.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a variant of hulk with thors worthiness enchantment , giving him asgardian armour and my guess is the sword and energy is just his gamma radiating out of him, maybe some odin enchanted sword 'whoever holds this sword if he be worthy, should possess the powers of thorhulk' its just gamma lightning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).